# How to compare the length of each element in two seperate list in python?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner to python, I got this problem just could not figure out :

I have two list:

```
a = ["AAAA", "BB", "CCC", "DDDDD"]

b = ["E", "FFF", "GGGG", "HH"]
```

These two list are user input, with unknown number or length of each element.

I want to compare the length of each correspondent index position, and return the length result in a list or string.

Let's say, `len(a[0]) > len(b[0])`, and `len(a[1]) < len(b[1])`, and so forth, take the long one, and then return the result like:

```
c = ["AAAA", "FFF", "GGGG", "DDDDD"]
```

and based on the length of each element, return a list:

```
d = [4, 3, 4, 5]
```

I struggled days on this. Please help! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Can you please show some attempts of what you have tried so far?

Comment: `d = list(map(max, map(len, a), map(len, b)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use zip() to iterate two or more lists parallely

```
a = ["AAAA", "BB", "CCC", "DDDDD"]

b = ["E", "FFF", "GGGG", "HH"]

c = []

for a1,b1 in zip(a,b):
  if len(a1) >= len(b1):
    c.append(a1)
  else:
    c.append(b1)

d = [len(x) for x in c]
```

Output:

```
c = ['AAAA', 'FFF', 'GGGG', 'DDDDD']]
d = [4,3,4,5]
```

Comment: The code so clear to me, answer accpeted, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two line using list comprehension:

```
c = [A if len(A)>len(B) else B for A,B in zip(a,b)]

d = [len(A) for A in c]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max` in a list comprehension with `len` as the `key` argument for the comparator. Then to get a list of lengths that is simply calling `len` on each element in the prior list.

```
>>> a = ["AAAA", "BB", "CCC", "DDDDD"]
>>> b = ["E", "FFF", "GGGG", "HH"]
>>> c = [max(i, key=len) for i in zip(a,b)]
>>> c
['AAAA', 'FFF', 'GGGG', 'DDDDD']
>>> d = [len(i) for i in c]
>>> d
[4, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

To return a list of the longest elements, the below works:

```
c = [a[i] if len(a[i]) > len(b[i]) else b[i] for i in range(len(b))]
['AAAA', 'FFF', 'GGGG', 'DDDDD']
```

for the maximum length for each index, the below returns the desired list:

```
d = [max(len(a[i]), len(b[i])) for i in range(len(b))]
[4, 3, 4, 5]
```